# Why Java is secure compared with other programming languages?

Tags: java, .net, security, programming-languages

Java vendor and community says that **"Java is more secure than other languages"**. But i want to know how?

If we look at programming in Java and .Net, they appear similar.

**Steps involved in .net programming**  [Click to know more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5532s8a.aspx)

1. **Write .net program.**
2. **Compiling your code to MSIL** (Compiling translates your source code into Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) and generates the required metadata).
3. **Compiling MSIL to native code** (At execution time, a just-in-time (JIT) compiler translates the MSIL into native code. During this compilation, code must pass a verification process that examines the MSIL and metadata to find out whether the code can be determined to be type safe).
4. **Running code**(The common language runtime provides the infrastructure that enables execution to take place and services that can be used during execution).

**Steps involved in java programming** [Click to know more](http://www.hubberspot.com/2012/03/how-to-create-compile-and-execute-java.html)

1. **Write a Java program**
2. **Compiling a Java Program** (Java compiler converts java source code to .class file which is a byte code)
3. **Program loading into memory by JVM**( JVM loads .class file into memory do byte code verification and converts .clsss file in machine language)
4. **Execution of Java program** (Whatever actions we have written in our Java program, JVM executes them by interpreting bytecode. If we talk about old JVM's they were slow, executed and interpreted one bytecode at a time. Modern JVM uses JIT compilation unit to which we even call just-in-time compilation).

If we look the steps in both the language they are almost same then **"Why is Java more secure compared with other languages?"**

Comment: Quote the reference also where did you read it.

Comment: One point triggers in my mind right now is, in .net you can still write "un-managed code" which won't run on top of CLR while in Java whatever you write is going to run on top of JRE only.

Comment: Yeah, reference (or link) will be helpful for others to understand that why one claims that.

Comment: Define "other"... there are more languages in computer world than several languages you've mentioned. Maybe original quote was talking about Java vs C, or Java vs Ada (which probably would be otherway around :) )

Comment: Java is more secure than previous languages. .net came after Java and has many of its best ideas. that said .net has more ways to break out of secure coding so its far easier to write an insecure program (you can in java too)

Comment: Define "secure." Do you mean application security? More secure due to managed memory? "Secure" is a broad term that could mean several things.

Comment: "secure means" your code security not application security.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many reasons why Java is a *safe* language, and it's definitely safer than some languages, but I think it's a stretch to say that it's safer than *all other* languages.

Java has a variety of safety features in place:

1. Automatic null-checking of references, bounds-checking of arrays, verification of casts, etc. to prevent the program from making type errors.  Compare this to C or C++, where these same errors (with a few exceptions) cause undefined behavior.
2. Verification of bytecode prior to execution.  This makes it impossible for the program to jump to an undefined instruction, or to try to perform an operation on a nonexistent object, or to make a type error at the instruction level, etc.  Compare this to C or assembly, where the program can jump to bad instructions, or try reading nonexistent parameters to functions (think `va_args`), etc.)
3. Runtime security checks when loading in new code.  The use of `SecurityManager` and `ClassLoader` make it easy for the Java runtime to prevent arbitrary code from executing on the computer by mediating access to system resources and preventing the program from loading or generating arbitrary code at runtime.  Compare this to C or C++, which can read and write arbitrary values, issue arbitrary system calls, generate and execute arbitrary code, etc.
4. Library-level safety of certain features.  For example, `String` is immutable and `final`, so a function that receives a `String` can verify the string and not have to worry about another thread changing its value.

This isn't a complete list of Java's safety features, but it should give you a sense of some of the design considerations in Java that are not present in other languages.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If [you're feeling evil](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20675/11333), you can mutate Strings in Java, so point 4 isn't true. It will certainly enforce it when you do things the usual way, but can give you a false sense of security.

Comment: @TimS. With an appropriate security manage installed, that code would trigger a security exception and fail.

Answer (score 3):

You mention you read some where but can you please re-read it because I guess when it was written the author would be comparing the JAVA with C++ / Fortran / C etc.

Also there is an old post you can read about the testability of security in http://www.veracode.com/blog/2010/06/which-tastes-better-for-security-java-or-net/

you can see both are same almost....

Comment: Yeah and we never know by other they could mean php too.. :)

Comment: Modified the question and added the links.

Comment: Thanks Dharmavir... are you friend of Gaurang Gajjar?

Answer (score 2):

Java or .Net programs, compared to C and the likes, are not subject to a few simple types of security vulnerabilities - buffer overflows or format string errors.

While this gets rid of some ways in which remote code execution can be obtained, Java does nothing to prevent, for example, any of web application vulnerabilities. It does not help with logic errors either.

Comment: The answer is still "it is not more secure than other languages, including .Net," you've been misinformed.