# Why payment gateways are only designed in Java language?

Tags: c#, java, .net

I have been talking with one java programmer and he told me that all of the Payment Gateways are designed in Java because they are secure in comparison of any .net based language.

Is it true?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209887/why-java-is-secure-compared-with-other-programming-languages

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not correct. .NET based languages and Java can each be programmed securely, or insecurely.

Answer (score 1):

Given the large number of high profile Java vulnerabilities which have surfaced over the years, I highly doubt the quality of the statement made by "one java programmer". This smells more of FUD spreading than any kind of factual statement.

Comment: Correct, i should better say exactly the same this "One java programmer" .